# notepad++ regular expression result deleted ()

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to add a prefix to the string:

```
            array(
                'id'=>'page-comment',
                'type' => 'switch',
                'title' => 'Show Comment Form on Page',
                'default' => '0',
                'on' => 'Yes',
                'off' => 'No',
            ),
```

Replace: `'title' => '(.*)'`

to: `'title' => __('\1\9', 'venedor')`

result

```
'title' => __'Show Comment Form on Page', 'venedor',
```

I need to characters () remained the same.
Line should look like result

```
'title' => __('Show Comment Form on Page', 'venedor'),
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you have to escape the parenthesis even in the replacement part:

```
'title' => __\('$1', 'venedor'\)
```

It' a Npp "feature"